# Would have removed .. in heroku deploy log

Tags: logging, deployment, heroku

a few days ago I started to see

```
 Would have removed best_in_place (2.0.2)
 Would have removed thor (0.16.0)
```

in my heroku deploy output.

It used to say that it removed the gem.

anyone know what's up with that?

**update**

heroku updated to latest ruby 1.9.3 and bundler cache cleaned fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533676/heroku-bundler-not-deleting-old-gems-versions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cleaning up the bundler cache when deploying to heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539232/cleaning-up-the-bundler-cache-when-deploying-to-heroku)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed with the release of Bundler 1.3.2, which is now in use on Heroku in the latest official Ruby buildpack.

Answer (score 13):

That's a bug in Heroku deployment configuration.
It writes a file .bundle/config which has a line:

```
BUNDLE_DRY_RUN: false
```

When bundler loads this global config file, it translates this to :dry_run => "false"
When it checks for this setting, it's checking settings[:dry_run], which is a string, which evaluates to true.

You can remove this line by some shell commands (heroku run bash):

```
mv -f .bundle/config .bundle/config.orig
sed '/BUNDLE_DRY_RUN/d' < .bundle/config.orig > .bundle/config
```

And then run

```
bundle clean
```

Comment: thank you, it is working fine and solving my issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533676/heroku-bundler-not-deleting-old-gems-versions)

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug in the bundler gem – essentially extra debugging info is being dumped to the screen. It should be patched in the next release. The removal would be from a cache, most likely because a newer version is available (latest `best_in_place` is 2.0.3, `Thor` 0.17.0). These can be safely ignored.

Comment: is this an open issue on bundler@github ?

Comment: I _believe_ it was discovered internally by bundler team and already been patched, just waiting for a release

Answer (score 6):

After some research, it appears this isn't a bug, but a feature!

as you can see here https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/pull/2237

a `dry_run` flag has been implmented to act as if gems would have been removed and instead of removing them it just prints that

the actual code is [here](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/runtime.rb#L168)

```
 if Bundler.settings[:dry_run]
          Bundler.ui.info "Would have removed #{output}"
        else
          Bundler.ui.info "Removing #{output}"
          FileUtils.rm_rf(gem_dir)
        end
```

as you can see, if dry_run it prints thats. else it removes the gem

so as this is a feature and not a bug, it is not going to be fixed any time soon. This leaves a question for heroku (which I am waiting for a reply) as to why they are using dry_run..

Note for those that aren't aware - This bloats `slug` size

Answer (score 4):

@Roman explication is correct.

If you have a custom buildpack (or you can easily fork it ans use it) it can be fixed in one line

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/master/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb

line 408-409 from

```
puts "Cleaning up the bundler cache."
pipe "bundle clean"
```

to

```
puts "Cleaning up the bundler cache."
pipe "bundle config --delete dry_run"
pipe "bundle clean"
```

bundle config --delete remove the config (note the underscore) and, by default `dry-run` is false.

Comment: Cool, this I call team work and cross-polination :) I'm going to use a custom build pack now.